# What that mean: Compare two strings $a and $b in length-constant time?

Tags: php, function, logic

While learning Password Hashing and saving in DB, I found this article: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode

Everything was clear except this function that I can't Understand exactly why not used normal equality? And what is meant by: **Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.**

```
// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
    $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
    {
        $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
    }
    return $diff === 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd assume it refers to a 'equals' function that has constant execution time to guard against time-based attacks. Length-constant probably refers to the fact that the execution time is irrelevant of the string length. Of course, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you usually compare if two strings are equal or not, the algorithm stops if it encounters the first unequality.

Like this: "aaa" == "aba"? First character? Both "a". Second character? "a" isn't "b", so stop here to save time. The last character does not get compared.

When comparing security relevant strings, an attacker might get a clue which character is correct and which is wrong because of the runtime of such a comparison function.

Consider for a moment the unsafe practice of having plain text passwords. If the attacker could find out whether or not the first character of his guessed password is correct by measuring how long the password comparison runs, he needs only about 62 guesses (alphabetic characters lower and upper case, and numbers) to know the first letter. With one letter the runtime was longer because that first letter was identical to the real password, and the second letter got compared. Now that second letter gets iterated. And after 62 more guesses, is known.

This weakens security a lot, because without knowing if the first letter is right, you'd need 62*62 guesses for a two-letter password. With a clue, you only need 62 + 62 guesses.

A length-constant comparison function compares all the letters, and only at the end reveals whether or not the strings match. That way you cannot get a clue which letter is already right.

Hashing strings mixes up things a bit, but because you cannot know if the attacker has pre-generated a bunch of hashes, or is generating them on the fly and does NOT brute-force the corresponding password if the hash would not match, you do not want anybody to know WHERE that hash does not match. It's a small added security component, but a very important one.

Comment: In short, this way we can prevent time-based attack, I get it thanks

Comment: seems like the loop could have been avoided if $diff was not 0 via `$diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);` without dirupting the logic concerning time.

Comment: That would completely circumvent the whole purpose of having such a function. It's reason is to be equally slow for every input. Explicitly no shortcuts for any case.

Comment: @Sven: but even with the original code, one can guess password length, as strings smaller than password will return quickly.

Comment: You missed the fact that we do not compare the plain text passwords, but their hashes. And such hashes have the same length, no matter how unsafe the original password has been. My example used the plain text password scenario simply to illustrate why using a non-length-constant string comparison function will be used to reveal information. Abusing it against hashes sound way harder, but why take any chances?

Comment: If we are truly comparing same-length hashes, then we don't need the `$diff` line at all.

Comment: Which line are you referring to, exactly?